# Storing user id and password hash in a cookie for auto login? Is vBulletin-type authentication acceptable?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, cookies

I'm setting up a user account system on my web site. The SO consensus seem to be reflected in [this SO question/article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication/477579#477579). It recommends [this approach](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) by Charles Miller to store the username and a large random number 1) in a cookie and 2) in a separate table in the DB. The user can be reauthenticated in each subsequent session by querying this table using the cookie (if it exists). If a match is found, then a new `$_SESSION` is set for that session. It supports simultaneous logins from different computers.

My question...

Prior to reading security questions on SO, I was thinking about storing user information in a way similar to the way vBulletin does it. As I understand it, they store the user id and the hashed password in separate cookies on the user's browser.

After the user logs in, they use a `$_SESSION` variable (e.g. something like `$_SESSION['user_hash']`) to maintain the authentication for each page request. I don't have access to vBulletin software, but I assume that `$_SESSION['user_hash']` is maintained in a separate MySQL table along with another piece of identifying information - e.g. user id/password hash/other - in order to enable logins from different computers.

I was thinking about creating the hash by doing this:

```
$_SESSION['user_hash'] = $random_hash = sha1(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

For future sessions, if `$_SESSION['user_hash']` does not exist, then those two cookies can be used to auto-login this person for a new session. I would plan on implementing the `$_SESSION` security measures outlined in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking) .

Is the vBulletin approach acceptable from a security standpoint? If storing the user id and the hashed password in a cookie is problematic, would encrypting them alleviate some security concerns? Or could something else be done to secure the cookies?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that there is far more potential for session hijacking than with a standard session cookie. If I were to steal that cookie, I would potentially be able to access the user's account for as long as they don't change their password. If session authentication uses a session ID that's unique to the session, it's easy enough to set the sessions to time out after a period of inactivity by storing the last activity time in the database.

Another thing is that I would argue you are overcomplicating your own code. You're already using PHP's sessions, which I've always found to work very well, so why not just store the PHP session ID and a link to the user record in the database in your user sessions table? What more do you gain from setting another cookie with your own hash in it? That's why PHP is such a nice language to use because a lot of these high level functions, such has session handling, are already done for you

Comment: Since vBulletin has so many users, I figured they must know what they're doing. But, as you say, with the user ID and the password hash, a hacker could login to the stolen account as long as the password wasn't changed. [This approach](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/), which is listed in a SO article/question, seems more secure than the vBulletin approach. By creating a cookie w/ the user ID and some random series of letter/numbers, it would be harder for a hacker to gain 'permanent' access.

Comment: Regarding the alternate approach (linked in comment above)... if you assign the user a cookie (with the user ID + an unguessable hash) and place the cookie and the user ID in an authentication table, I suppose you could also have a column that would allow the authentication information to expire---say after a week or so? I could see the authentication table getting out of hand if a user logged in from several computers. I suppose the table could be pruned every so often, removing old authentication codes.

Comment: I see what you mean about the session table getting out of hand, but it should be a fairly simple task to prune it. My approach tends to be to store the PHP session ID against a user account with login time, last activity time and sometimes IP address (if I want to tie a session to an IP address). Then each authenticated page request updates the last activity time. The authentication also looks at the last activity time and if it's more than a set time ago (stored in system prefs), will force the user to a login page. That way the only thing I'm relying on the browser for is the session id

Comment: This also means you have a very good security log of who's accessed the system when :-)