# is my session id generated before login?

Tags: php, security, session, sessionid

I read about session vulnerability in the php manual and came across this issue: I need my server/code to generate the session-id AFTER successfully authenticating the user.

Now, I am not sure when php sets the session Id. My php application is MVC-like, and everything goes through index.php, and at the top of index.php I have session.start() since every single page (after login) uses sessions.

Is this a vulnerability risk? Or, should I put it like this: Does this mean that upon first arrival to my site, even before login, does the server set a session id for that user? Does session.start() set a user ID, or is a session-id not generated until I set my first session variable, ie. until I do $_SESSION['foo']='bar'?

If a session is actually generated already upon session.start(), I guess a good idea would be to regenerate the session-id after authenticating, does that in that case solve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

The session ID is generated when you run `session_start()`.

Best practice is to refresh the session ID upon login using `session_regenerate_id()`.

Answer (score 4):

PHP generates a new session ID when `session_start` is called and no valid session ID was passed. So in your case the user will already get a session ID when visiting the login form page.

This is not a security vulnerability in general but it can be if your application is vulnerable to [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation). To avoid that there are [some counter-measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking/5082524#5082524). The most important with regard to authentication is to generate a new session ID and invalidate the old one. You can do that by calling [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) before storing the user information in the session:

```
if ($userIsAuthentic) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['user-id'] = 12345;
    /* … */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Or, should I put it like this: Does this mean that upon first arrival to my site, even before login, does the server set a session id for that user?*

Yes, it does.

*I guess a good idea would be to regenerate the session-id after authenticating, does that in that case solve the issue?*

You are correct.

*Does session.start() set a user ID, or is a session-id not generated until I set my first session variable...*

In any case, regenerating the session ID on user login costs you essentially nothing, and even if you don't set `$_SESSION` variables for non-logged-in users, you are covered if for some reason you decide to do so in the future.