# PHP Session Hijacking

Tags: php, session

I have a question regarding session hijacking in PHP.  I have been reading about it this morning and I have a few questions that just weren't answered clearly in the documentation I read.

Can a user change their session on my website? i.e. if they have a session of X when the login, can they change that session to Y, or Z, if they so choose?

I thought that sessions were set by the browser and they couldn't be changed, but all of this session hijacking stuff I've been reading has put some doubt in my mind.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The term "session" is overloaded to mean different things on the server and in the browser. Browser sessions are at best tenuously connected to server sessions. "Session hijacking" refers to server [sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_management#Web_server_session_management).

Server-side, a session has an ID (which is passed between the client and server), content (stored on the server) and potentially other properties, such as last access time. The session ID is usually passed as a cookie. In PHP the default name for the cookie is "PHPSESSID". If cookies aren't available, PHP will (optionally) use a query string parameter of the same name ("PHPSESSID"). This cookie (or query param) can easily be changed and therefore the session identifier can be changed too.

The *contents* of a session (i.e. containing the login state of a user) cannot be changed by the client, the data is stored on the server and can only be changed by a PHP script on that server. Note that in a shared-hosting environment (shared by other services or users), the sessions can be overwritten if using the default session storage directory (`/tmp`). To protect against that, either use a database through [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) or set a custom session directory using [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) with the proper directory permissions set (preferably 700 which means that only the owner (the PHP user) can read and write to it).

To protect against session hijacking, you must have other ways to identify the user against a session. This can be a user agent, IP address or another cookie. The previously mentioned methods are just workarounds, best way to protect against stealing of the session cookie is by using HTTPS if a session is involved. Do not forget to set the `httponly` flag to `true` using [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Client-side, "session" is again overloaded and used in various contexts (e.g. session managers, which restore open pages when a browser is opened, session cookies and [`sessionStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)). We can try to combine these meanings (into what is by no means a standard one) by saying a browser session consists of a collection of views and their associated data. (By "view" I mean roughly tabs in tabbed browsers and windows in non-tabbed browsers; the DOM `window` object exposes a view to JS.) Each view has a history, a current page and page data. Page data for pages in the same domain is shared between views in a session; if two pages are in different domains or different sessions, they don't share data. Exiting the browser closes all open session(s), possibly saving part of the session(s) (e.g. histories, current pages, `sessionStorage`) so that a session manager can re-open them. Session cookies are cookies that are discarded when a session is closed; in other words, session cookies are non-persistant. Though a session cookie may hold a session ID, the two concepts are [orthogonal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthogonal) (sense 4; session cookies can hold things other than session IDs, and session IDs can be stored in persistant cookies).

Whether two different views are in the same collection depends on the browser. For example, one browser may consider a session to consist of all tabs within a single window; separate windows are separate sessions. [IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx) lets users create new sessions via the "New session" menu item. Otherwise, new windows and tabs are opened in the same session. Privacy modes also create new sessions.

In summary, browser sessions are indeed set by the browser, though it provides users various means of controlling browser sessions: creating new sessions, changing the history and current page in a view by browsing, saving and restoring sessions. A user could even change session data by editing sessions saved on disk, though this isn't a feature afforded by the browser. None of this has anything to do with session hijacking. Server sessions are created and managed by the server, but users can (attempt to) switch server sessions by changing the session ID their browser passes back to the server, which is the basis for session hijacking.

See also [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081025/).

Comment: Session hijacking refers to stealing the session cookie. This can be most easily accomplished when sharing a local network with other computers. E.g. at Starbucks. Example... a user with session Y is browsing James's website at Starbucks. I am listening in on their network traffic, sipping my latte. I take user with session Y's cookies for James's website and set my browser to use them. Now when I access James's site, James's site thinks I am the user with session Y. The only way to stop this is to use end to end https.

Comment: I think that's why Lekensteyn mentionned the session_set_cookie_params function which you can use to specify that no session cookie will be used if the connexion is not done through https.

Comment: @Arkh: actually, I've made an edit after Chris mentioned it. Still, if spyware succeeds in copying the session ID, the other mentioned ideas should protect you a little. Of course, it is not a bullet-proof method, but still better than nothing and if you're infected, you've more worries other than a PHP session. (unless a banking website is run with that session ;) )

Comment: What exactly changes when using an SSL secured connection? Are sessions save then?

Comment: @phpheini An session identifier is kept safe (secret) in the sense that it is not transmitted in plaintext over the network connection, meaning that anyone who is intercepting the traffic can only see some random bits, but not the actual data (confidentiality). This does not just apply to session cookies, but requests and responses in general.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: So as far as I understood even with SSL a user could change the SessionID (either in the URL or Cookie) to something which will give him e.g. access to a restricted area?

Comment: @phpheini Of course (s)he can, SSL only ensures that the the server and client can have a conversation without eavesdroppers intercepting it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Does changing the SessionID allow the user to access restricted areas then?

Comment: @binoculars Yes, it does, especially if no other mechanisms are in place to validate the session. Example: stackoverflow.com identifies you with the `usr` cookie which has the form `t=XXX&s=yyy`. A high-rep user can for example access moderation tools (which would be your "restricted area"). If someone managed to tap the unencrypted HTTP traffic, then this session cookie is trivially extracted. Since this ID is not bound to an IP address, the attacker can use this cookie to gain access to account of the high-rep user. (I just tried this with `curl -b 'usr=t=...' stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Lekensteyn I see. I do have a PositiveSSL certificate. Does this eliminate this thread completely?

Comment: @binoculars The system is as secure as the weakest chain. Even if your website uses https, it is vulnerable to session hijacking when: (1) you forget to set the `httpOnly` flag for session cookies (it takes a trivial request to reveal the session cookie unencrypted) or (2) you include scripts from untrusted sources (including your own website over unencrypted HTTP). That were just a few client-side vulnerabilities, on the server-side you must consider the points in this answer and also not do stupid things like redirecting to an arbitrary URL with the session ID attached to it.

Answer (score 5):

A user can change his session at any time. It's just a random string stored in a cookie in the users browser, and therefore it is very simple for the user to change it.

As the actual content of the session is stored on your server, you could for instance store the user's ip address, user agent or similar to make it harder to steal sessions from each other, by checking if this information still matches each time a new http request is made.

Answer (score 3):

No actually user can not change the actual session value at your website but can change the session id that is used to track the session this session id is stored on client browser by your website usually name "PHPSESSID" in cookie which are also known as session cookie. When a session is started on a site it stores the unique id corresponding to that session in the respective client browser in form of cookie named as "PHPSESSID". So if user is able to get PHPSESSID of any other user and it can replace his PHPSESSID with the victims PHPSESSID and it will result in session hijacking.
I am using PHP context here.