# Session deletion lifetime

Tags: php, session, cookies

Are PHP sessions automatically destroyed after the browser is closed, or do they stay on the server for ever, and are later accessible by the Server Cookie Id? (in case you do not destroy them before the browser exit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are deleted by Garbage collector. Lifetime can be adjusted by `session.gc_maxlifetime`.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483092/php-session-hijacking)

Answer (score 2):

The session cookie usually called PHPSESSID is destoryed with the closing of the browser. However the actual data files remain on the server until they are deleted. But, they are impossible to find without that PHPSESSID cookie reference so for all practicality, they are gone with the closing of the browser.