# Is using session var to act as security token in php ok?

Tags: php, security, session

I want to add some type of security token when a user is editing database content.
I would like to check that the user has the authorization to edit and once that is establish I would like to have that token follow the user as they move through the edit pages. My thoughts are to set a session variable and then keep referring to that session variable. But my gut is telling me that something might be wrong with that idea. 
I guess I could keep requesting the info form the database at each page.

Comment: That would leave you vulnerable to [session hijacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483092/php-session-hijacking)

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. now I have a direction to search. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is fine. Although you need to be careful:

- Employ TLS/SSL to encrypt the session identifier using HTTPS.
- Set the Secure Flag on the session cookie so that it is never leaked over plain HTTP.
- Employ HSTS to ensure users only connect to your site over HTTPS.
- Refresh the session token on login/logout to protect against session fixation.
- Never transmit the session identifier in the URL as it is vulnerable to leakage via `referer` header, history and proxy/server logs.

Check out the [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) for further reading.