# PHP Login will not redirect after logging in

Tags: php, mysql

I hate to be confusing, but I'm not sure at this point if the problem lies within the PHP Login not working, or if the redirecting isn't working.
I'll post what I have so far in both the Login.php and the target page I'm trying to redirect to.

Login.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["Login"])){ 
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('users') or die("cannot select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user='".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['user'];
$dbpassword=$row['pass'];
}

if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: ./Programs/Content/Home.php");
}
} else {
echo "Invalid username or password!";
} } else {
echo "All fields are required!"; }}?> }
```

Then there's just some CSS and basic HTML stuff, but here's the form itself:

```
<div class="login">
 <form action="" method=POST>
    <center>
    <p><input id="user" name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username"></p>
    <p><input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </center>
</form> </div>
```

And here's the header code for Home.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
header("location:../../Login.php");
} else {
?>
```

then there's the page contents, and at the end there's:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is **($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)** really true?

Comment: _Stop_ using `mysql*` right now.

Comment: How would I check to see if it is? Sorry, I'm kind of new to PHP and MYSQL..

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @MissSylvia By adding some output, like .. `echo`.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You are also using PLAIN TEXT passwords. ___Bad Girl___

Comment: forgot to add name to submit button. I have mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly easy, everyone learns in time. Perhaps some pointers to a secure account system would be the best thing to do here.

Comment: @GillBates cool, I am just pointing out all the things I can see that OP needs to look at

Comment: @RiggsFolly Plus, girl might be inappropriate here. OP could be an [an apache](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/AH-64_Apache) :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a name attribute to the submit button so `if(isset($_POST["Login"]))` will be false all the time.

change

```
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

to

```
<input  name="Login" type="submit" value="Login">
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so so so much. I've been struggling with this for hours on end.

Comment: No issues, that's what stackoverflow is for, kindly marked it as answered if it solved your problem :).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your `input` element doesn't have a `name` associated with it. as [Danyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40153247/1870760) already said. But there's much more you should worry about with this code.

This is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so I'll only point out the obvious problems/errors you have. (although posting on code review certainly wouldn't hurt)

First off, get a decent IDE to code your PHP in, this will give you auto indentation, this increases readability by *a ton* as you'll be able to see where scope begins and ends much more easily:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Login"])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('users') or die("cannot select DB");

        $query   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user='" . $user . "' AND pass='" . $pass . "'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows != 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $dbusername = $row['user'];
                $dbpassword = $row['pass'];
            }

            if ($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $user;

                /* Redirect browser */
                header("Location: ./Programs/Content/Home.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "All fields are required!";
    }
}
?>
```

Now for the problems:

- **Don't** ever use `mysql_*` again, these functions have been deprecated for a long time and were even removed in PHP 7, instead, use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
- **Don't** blindly insert user-entered data into your query :
  `"SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user='".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'"`. This leaves you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work), use [Prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php) instead.
- **Don't** ever save your passwords in plain-text but rather use something like [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and save the result of that in the database. Then when you need to check if a user correctly entered their password just use the function again on the `$_POST` value and check it against the value in the database.
- You're probably also vulnerable to [Session Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483092/php-session-hijacking) but that's a later concern.