# PHP Session Security: usefulness of checking $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Tags: php, security, session-hijacking

Threads such as [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking) and some people like Chris Shiflett recommend checking the user agent ( `$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ) to help check for session validity. Some [resources](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html) even recommend something like this:

```
<?php

$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$string .= 'SHIFLETT';

/* Add any other data that is consistent */

$fingerprint = md5($string);

?>
```

However, [Chris Snyder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233184) says that "the universe of browser agents is miniscule in comparison to the universe of users, so it is impossible for each user to have an individual user agent. Furthermore, it isn't hard to spoof a user agent. And so there is little real point in checking this metric as a proof of session validity" (Chapter 7, pg 103).

It's very difficult to know what to do when one encounters conflicting advice, and when some of the advice may be out-of-date (such as the Shiflett/PHPSec example above, whose timestamp seems to be Friday, March 18, 2005). Newer advice such as Snyder's (date of publication: December 9, 2010) would seem to be better, but is this always so? (For example, in spite of spending a lot of time recommending the use of `mysqli`, Snyder completely ignores what Stack Overflow users seem to agree is the better choice -- `PDO` -- so I'm not totally sold on Snyder as the ultimate Trustworthy Expert).

So I guess my question has two parts, one specific (should I bother examining the user agent?) and one more general (whose advice should I trust when it comes to the latest thinking in PHP Security?), with my obvious bias being "trust the people on Stack Overflow!" -- or I wouldn't be asking in the first place, because crowd-sourcing the most current thinking is often the best idea.

Following useful discussion in the comments w/ @Radu, to clarify the HTTPS question --

Snyder seems to be saying two things: 1.) HTTPS makes other tools less necessary or unnecessary. 2.) In situations where one cannot use HTTPS, it is still not really useful to check the user agent (and this seems to be the point where he disagrees with some possibly older advice).

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about mysqli vs. PDO. They both support prepared statements and are both much better than ext/mysql, PDO just isn't tied to MySQL as its RDBMS.

Comment: Chris, I agree that PDO and mysqli are very similar and both better than ext/mysql, I just found it strange that the author didn't mention PDO at all. Overall, the book seems really up-to-date and helpful, but StackOverflow inevitably gets the last word just by being constantly updated (taken with a grain of salt, as always).

Comment: Yeah, I've come across a lot more material on mysqli than PDO, too. PDO is a slightly newer addition to PHP (included with PHP5.1+ as opposed to 5.0+), maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the man in the middle can hijack the session ID, then he should have absolutely no problem in sending the same user agent, so I don't think this will get you anywhere. This is security by obscurity.

If you want real protection, use HTTPS.

Comment: I'm assuming that the goal is to use HTTPs, but to also use whatever other tools will also help. I believe Snyder is saying, "hey, once you've used HTTPS, there's no point wasting time also checking the user agent".

Comment: @Carole, that's true. Once you use HTTPS, then all these things won't matter anymore, since forgery attacks will become impractical.

Comment: Thinking about that whole chapter some more, I think he's saying two things. 1.) HTTPS makes other tools less necessary or unnecessary. 2.) In situations where one cannot use HTTPS, it is still not really useful to check the user agent (and this seems to be the point where he disagrees with some possibly older advice).

Comment: @Carole, indeed, again, this is security by obscurity. Anything in the HTTP request can be spoofed. If the hacker doesn't know that he needs to include the user agent as well, he'll easily figure it out. In the end, he can simply send the whole request just as he gets it from the victim. And if he's only interested in spying, then that's exactly what he'll do by default.

Comment: This assumes a 'man-in-the-middle' attack method where the hacker sees the http headers in clear text and hence sees the session cookie and all traffic. Hence what you are saying (encrypt with ssl) would be the simply answer. However, is it not conceivable that an attacker may gain access to the session cookie by some other means? A javascript perhaps. In which case, would not checking the user agent acually give a valid additional level of security? After all, security is all about adding barriers right.

Answer (score 0):

The user agent is not totally fool proof by itself but it adds thin layer on top of other security. There is debate on what should go to fingerprint. But nonetheless it adds to defense-on-depth principle. You can set a cookie and use that in combination with user agent and specific word to make fingerprint.
My point is, it adds to security though little!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sessions is that you just need the session ID to use that session. If you know a valid session ID, you can use that session. That’s how sessions work.

Now some suggest to use an additional datum to verify the validity to use a certain session by a certain client. The user agent ID is such a suggested datum as it is some kind of unique (see [Panoptoclick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/) to test your own) and doesn’t change during the session (in opposite to some other informations provided by the client).

But this only lowers the likelihood of Session Fixation and prevents the accidental use of a foreign session in case of Session Hijacking. Because an attacker could try to obtain the victim’s user agent ID and spoof it when fixing or hijacking the session. And here it doesn’t matter whether you store the user agent ID in plain or as a (salted) hash.

Better use the already proven protection measures.