# Scraping: session ID from browser works, but session ID from scraping doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, screen-scraping, session-cookies

*Note: I've replaced the last 5 chars of the session IDs with 'x's for obvious reasons*

I'm scraping a web site. I can see, in the browser, that logging in sets a cookie value called `PHPSESSID`. No problem, I can scrape that:

```
superagent
    .post(loginUrl)
    .send(loginDetails)
    .end(function(err, res){
        var setCookieValue = res.headers['set-cookie'][0]
        var sessionID = cookieParser.parse(setCookieValue).PHPSESSID
        console.log(sessionID)
```

Returns:

```
37c3bog3tf6erp2i6ss5vxxxxx
```

Which looks like a PHP session ID. Great! Now to use the session ID:

```
superagent
.get(loggedInURL)
.set('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID'=sessionID)
.end(err, res)
```

Redirects me to the login page. But **the session ID I got manually from the browser, in the exact same format, works fine**:

```
var fakeSessionID = 'a1oslk341uoht8p6009q5xxxxx'
superagent
.get(loggedInURL)
.set('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID='+fakeSessionID)
```

Will return the loggedInURL, with the full HTML of a logged in user.

**Why isn't the session ID I'm scraping working?**

- The format is identical
- The character count is the same (26 characters)

There is nothing asides from the session ID that's different between the working and non-working code.

What could be making the difference?

Comment: Does the scraped cookie contain control characters, e.g. new line at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has some [dubious extra security for sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php) such as [checking `Referer`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.referer-check).

Some sites may additionally [check `User-Agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930167/php-session-security-usefulness-of-checking-sessionhttp-user-agent).

Comment: I have switched to using superagent's persistent option, eg, `var agent = superagent.agent()`. This takes care of referers, cookies, and other persistence-related matters for me. Since the answer above was the closest to that solution I'm marking it as correct and giving you this emoji corn: 

Answer (score 2):

You might try throwing a different user-agent attribute in the header in the call to superagent for both GET and POST:

```
  .set('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0')
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion but no change.

Comment: You might try reading through this post:  https://contourline.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/using-superagent-to-authenticate-a-user-agent-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

You code looks like you aren't replacing the string "sessionID" with the actual sessionID value...

```
superagent
.get(loggedInURL)
.set('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=sessionID')
.end(err, res)
```

Should be something like?

```
superagent
.get(loggedInURL)
.set('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID='+sessionID)
.end(err, res)
```

I think...

Comment: You're right, but that was an error made when making a test case for StackOverflow. My real code has the quote in the right place. Thanks for pointing this out though.