# Storing session for use in members area

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have created a registration/login system for my members area. Once the user has logged in I want to store a session variable that I can use to retrieve data associated to the user from the database.

Should I in encrypt the variable in any way? The data I want as a variable will either be the username or the id, which is best?

Should session ids be regenerated in anyway and when??

Comment: Session data is kept on the server and is never visible to or accessible by a user unless you provide an interface for it. The only thing stored in the client by default is the session's ID string in a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should regenerate your session id after a successful login/logout. For security reasons, I would reccomend to ask the user for his password if he want's to perform a critical action (changing important data, deleting account or submit an order for example).

As AurimasL stated, you don't have to worry about session data on the server side. I reccomend this reading, if you are on a shared host, because then there are some security aspects: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/5.html

Answer (score 1):

Data storage in session is considered to be "safe", so you dont need encrypt-decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Session IDs are stored like a cookie on the client's machine, and are passed back to the server for every single request.  This is how PHP determines what information to load into a session once it receives the request.

Since sessions live on the server and not on the client, you only need to worry about [session hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking) in regards to whether the information stored in them is secure or not.  The answer to your question is no, I would not try to encrypt the information that is stored in session.

Answer (score 0):

Just an add in the comments bellow,

Keep in mind that creating a sessions are expensive for your server app. Sometimes is a good idea stores the id in the session and other informations in cookies (informations that dont need security as the username).

Comment: This cost in storing data in a persistent store such as MySQL can be circumvented by implementing a cache layer (memcached or tokyo tyrant for example) and in which to store session data.