# Share Laravel session with custom PHP

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I have Laravel 4 application with custom login on `example.com`, and my session driver is `database`.

On subdomain example `custom.example.com` I have a custom PHP application that should use same user base and share this login.

Also I have another subdomain `l4.example.com` with another Laravel 4 application sharing the same user base and login, and here I can use same session, but with custom application on `custom.example.com` when I try to do

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

I get `Undefined variable: _SESSION`.

So is there a way to share Laravel 4 session with custom PHP application over subdomain

Comment: [Answer from this post][1] will surely help you. It's pretty much the same situation.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968414/share-laravel-authentication-session-with-php

Comment: Doesn't work. It is still only visible inside Laravel application

Comment: You should store Laravel Auth Sessions in database and from `custom.example.com` try to check if the session is active or not from Laravel database. Also See Laravel [Database Sessions](http://laravel.com/docs/session#database-sessions)