# I want to figure out how cookies/ session variables interact to validate a user session

Tags: authentication, php, cookies, session-management, secure-coding

---I have been experimenting on cookies/ session ids and have a little trouble digesting in the concepts.
 I'm working on a Debian distro. Using Burp to capture/alter requests/ responses. What I know is below.

a. Cookies get stored in the client machine database at /root/.mozilla/firefox/pya18ecc.default/cookies.sqlite. In the moz_cookies table. I'm using sqlite3 to access the database.

b. Session variables are getting stored in /var/lib/PHP5 on the server.

The PHP code on the SERVER is below

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
if($connection->connect_error) die ($connect->connect_error);

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
   isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
    {
        $username = mysql_entities_fix($connection,$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
        $password = mysql_entities_fix($connection,$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result = $connection->query($query);

        if(!$result) die ($connection->error);
        elseif ($result->num_rows) 
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);    
            $result->close();
            $salt1="!@#$";
            $salt2="$#@!";
            $token = hash('ripemd128',"$salt1$password$salt2"); 

            if($token == $row[3])
                {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['forename'] = $row[0];
                    $_SESSION['surname'] = $row[1];
                        echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi '$row[0]' you are logged
                            in as '$row[2]'";
                    die("<p><a href = continue.php> CLICK HERE TO CONTINUE</a></p>");
                }
            else    {die("Invalid Username/ Password Combination");}            
        }
        else
            {
                die("Invalid Username/ Password Combination");
            }
    }
else
    {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
                header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
                die("Please enter your username and password to Login");
    }
    $connection->close();
function mysql_entities_fix($connection,$var)
    {
        return htmlentities(mysql_entities_string($connection,$var));
    }
function mysql_entities_string($connection,$var)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslahes($var);
        return $connection->real_escape_string($var);

    }
?>
```

1. When I send in the request(1), it lookes like this.

request(1)

```
 GET /ses3.php HTTP/1.1
 Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686;      rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

2. The response(1) is a login page (Basic HTTP authentication)

response(1)

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 07:27:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 48
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Please enter your username and password to Login
```

----Till here there has no exchange of session ids or cookies. (If I'm wrong, prompt me ?)

3. I responded with the username and password and the request(2) is

request(2)

```
GET /ses3.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0     Iceweasel/31.5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic YnNtaXRoOm15c2VjcmV0
```

---- On forwarding the above request what I observe is that I've received the Session id: cl5mi7tbhdnobpv8kkau7thjo6 in the /var/lib/PHP5 even before forwarding the response(2). That's because Server
has created the same and is ready to fowrward it in the response (2)

4. The response(2) is

response(2)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 07:36:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=cl5mi7tbhdnobpv8kkau7thjo6; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-    revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 117
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

Bill Smith : Hi 'Bill' you are logged
                             in as 'bsmith'<p><a href = continue.php> CLICK HERE TO CONTINUE</a></p>
```

----Now on checking SELECT * FROM moz_cookies, I'm not seeing any cookies which are getting saved on the client m/c. So where are they getting saved ?  (This is my first question)

5. Next I've deleted the session variable "cl5mi7tbhdnobpv8kkau7thjo6" from the server and again have hit the
   refresh button on the client's browser. The request(3)/ response(3) are below

request(3)

```
GET /ses3.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: PHPSESSID=cl5mi7tbhdnobpv8kkau7thjo6
Authorization: Basic YnNtaXRoOm15c2VjcmV0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

response(3)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2015 07:50:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 117
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

Bill Smith : Hi 'Bill' you are logged
                            in as 'bsmith'<p><a href = continue.php> CLICK   HERE TO CONTINUE</a></p>
```

-----Now the Server has again got the same session variable set under the /var/lib/PHP5. Shouldn't the server not recognize the session variable ? Also if this is happening because of the saved Cookies, then why isn't I'm able to see them under moz_cookies table .....    Please explain ?(This is my second question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Till here there has no exchange of session ids or cookies. (If I'm wrong, prompt me ?)

No, that's correct. Until here, `session_start` hasn't been called, so there are no session cookies to exchange.

> Now the Server has again got the same session variable set under the /var/lib/PHP5. Shouldn't the server not recognize the session variable ?

It probably should, but it isn't. What I think is happening: When a client sends a session id, the server is happy to use it, even if it doesn't know it yet. This can (in theory) be used for [session fixation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking), which is why it is recommended to regenerate ids each time something in the session changes (in practice, `session.use_trans_sid` is set to `0` by default, which makes session fixation less of an issue).

What I find odd is that the data is also still there (I couldn't replicate this behavior). My guess would be that you are actually re-submitting the form?

> Also if this is happening because of the saved Cookies, then why isn't I'm able to see them under moz_cookies table

My guess is that the cookies are still in the browser memory. Did you try the same thing, but deleting the cookie via the browser interface?

**Misc**

I know that this is just a test script, but still:

- prepared statements are recommended over simple escaping.
- don't store plaintext passwords in sessions).
- don't echo user input unsanitized.
- hashes should be user specific, not site specific.
- htmlentities protects against XSS, not SQL injection, and should thus be applied when echoing data, not when inserting it into the database.

Comment: Cheers to your responses in detail. Yes I tried deleting the browser history/ cookies. Then on resubmitting the request/ refreshing the page (as you predicted), the GET variables/ Session variables were wiped out. So the basic authentication page got prompted again and a fresh Session id popped into the /var/lib/PHP5 folder.

Answer (score 2):

A few items to consider:

1. Cookies can be stored on disk or in memory. How they are stored is dependent on browser settings (.e.g Private Browsing mode in Firefox) and server settings (see [PHP docs on session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)).
2. HTTP connections can be cached using the Keep-Alive header.

It looks like you are set up to store session ids on the server in a file, but the browser cookie is being stored in memory rather than in a file, which is why you are seeing the PHP file but not a Firefox cookie file.

As to why the server is recognizing the session id even though you deleted the file, it looks like what is happening is that PHP knows the session is authenticated, meaning it must be cached in RAM on the server. (A PHP guru might be able to fill in the specifics of the session mechanics).

After receiving request 3, PHP looks for the session id file and when it doesn't see it, it writes the file again because it knows that the session is valid. This is expected behavior, because if you want to delete the session, you as a PHP programmer should be doing it in PHP rather than deleting the session id file behind the scenes.

You'll notice that the client sent the session id with request 3. The client will send the session id cookie with each request, but the server should not respond with the Set-Cookie instruction again during this session. The browser now has the session id cookie and can send it with each request, thus no further authentication is needed.

The weakness to this strategy is that it could leave open the possibility of session hijacking. If an attacker could obtain the session id cookie from your browser, they could execute commands against the server using your credentials.

Obtaining the session id may or may not be a trivial task for an attacker depending on many factors. If for instance the victim's computer is compromised with a virus or other malware controlled by the attacker, the attacker probably pwns the victim's computer at that point and can do whatever they want, including taking the session id. Other attacks use cross-site scripting ( XSS ) attacks to trick the victim's browser into divulging the session id.

There are specific defenses against XSS and session hijacking, again the subject is fairly complex and worth researching in detail. A more secure session, for instance, might use a one-time token that is changed with every response, although that strategy can be complicated by the use of asynchronous HTTP calls.

Comment: I agree with your point of session id getting stored in memory and thus PHP already knows about the valid session. Because the session continues even after the deletion of the physical session variable file on the server.