# Session validation destroys session

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables

This is my `Session` class:

```
class Session {

    const SESSION_VALIDATOR = 'validSession';

    /**
     * Starts the session
     */
    public static function init() {
        session_start();

        if (self::get(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR) !== true) {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            self::set(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR, true);
        }

        session_regenerate_id(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a value in the session
     * 
     * @param string|int $key
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a value from the session
     * 
     * @param string|int $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get($key) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key]))
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Destroys the session
     */
    public static function destroy() {
        unset($_SESSION);
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

At random times, the `SESSION_VALIDATOR` variable in the session seems not to be set, even though it isn't changed, and the session randomly destroys - even while a user is logged in. What causes this?

<strike>**Update 1:**

This appears to occur only at my localhost environment (`WAMPServer 2.5`), and not on my shared hosting account</strike>

**Update 2:**
It doesn't seem to be occur because the `Session::destroy()` method is called somewhere at accident, as when I throw an exception inside the method, the error occurs without the exception being thrown

**Update 3:**
Ignore update #1 - it also happens on my shared hosting account

**Update 4**
I tried andpei's answer, and the problem still occurs. This is the new `Session` class:

```
class Session {

    const SESSION_STARTED = true;
    const SESSION_NOT_STARTED = false;
    const SESSION_VALIDATOR = 'validSession';

    private $sessionState = self::SESSION_NOT_STARTED;
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        self::$instance->startSession();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function startSession() {
        if ($this->sessionState == self::SESSION_NOT_STARTED) {
            $this->sessionState = session_start();
        }

        if (self::get(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR) !== true) {
            $this->destroy();
            session_start();
            self::set(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR, true);
        }

        session_regenerate_id(false);

        return $this->sessionState;
    }

    public function set($name, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function get($name) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
            return $_SESSION[$name];
        }
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name) {
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }

    public function destroy() {
        if ($this->sessionState == self::SESSION_STARTED) {
            $this->sessionState = !session_destroy();
            unset($_SESSION);

            return !$this->sessionState;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This made me think the error was in the `SESSION_VALIDATOR` part:

```
if (self::get(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR) !== true) {
    $this->destroy();
    session_start();
    self::set(self::SESSION_VALIDATOR, true);
}
```

, so I removed it, and now the error doesn't occur anymore. Is this session validation really necessary? Why or why not? And if it's smart to keep it, how can the error be resolved?

Comment: Hard to tell, maybe the session is garbage collected on the server or the cookie expires?

Comment: Is this happening after the user has done nothing for some period of time? Remember sessions only remain for a finite time?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it sometimes happens after an immediate page refresh, but most of the time it takes a few

Comment: @Cobra_Fast how can I check if it is garbage collected?

Comment: Is the page refresh after some time of just looking at a page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it happens most often when I spam the refresh button after the page's done loading

Comment: What's the point of generating a new session_id if you're not deleting/deactivating/devalidating the old one? Someone could still grab the old session

Comment: @SanderBackus how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a design problem, because you unintentionally create more than one instance of the `Session` object, which then all may have a different value for `SESSION_VALIDATOR`.

To avoid this problem you should use in OOP the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html). Instead of creating an instance by `= new Session` the `getInstance()` method will return always the same instance object.

You could try this example to create a [class Session with a Singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#102460).

**Update to comment**

If you do not instantiate the `Session` object, then it may get deleted by the [Garbage Collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php), because there is no reference to it. As a result `SESSION_VALIDATOR` is also deleted. In that case you destroy the session (_unset,_destroy,_start), which logs off an user.

You could try the example from above, which will solve the problem by use the singleton pattern.

Than the whole object is stored as a static value.

**Update to question about `SESSION_VALIDATOR`**

It's a design problem, because you store a state at server-side which depends on a session-state at client-side, i.e. the garbage collector runs (server) or the browser deletes cookies or logs off (client).

In theory this means that HTTP is stateless and a session is used to overcome this problem. In practice this means you have to read a value from the session and decide if a login is valid or not.

So, **your validation has to be a function instead of a `SESSION_VALIDATOR`** variable, which returns a boolean depending on the session state, its values and your user database, i.e with a Singleton.

But do **not** store something like login=true in your session. Use values which you could validate with your user database.

Also take a look at **OWASP** [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet)

similar questions:

- [PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328/2025944)
- [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081025/2025944)

Comment: How is more than one instance of `Session` created? It's a class with only static methods, and `Session::init()` is only called once, in the very beginning of the script