# Is $_SESSION accessible on the client side?

Tags: php, session, server, session-variables

I'm using `$_SESSION['captchaAnswer']` to store the answer to a captcha image. Obviously I want to store it somewhere not accessible to the client. Is this where I should be storing it?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. It's one place to house it as `$_SESSION` is not available client side. Whether or not it is appropriate for your use case is not determinable without more details and/or a code snippet.

Comment: yes you cant access session value from client unless you code it..... Anyway i can suggest to use hash in any server or client approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $_SESSION is a server-side super-global. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

The user's browser receives a cookie with the session id which it then sends with every request to that domain / sub-domain. This is used to identify which session PHP is meant to use. If you are going to be using the sessions for security purposes, please read up on session hijacking. [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking)

Comment: As Ignacy Debicki already wrote, $_SESSION is a server side storage and CANT be acces by the client. The client only gets hold of the id of a session (usually stored in a $_COOKIE), not the contents of that session. So it's save to use in your case.