# PHP :How key,value pairs are secured in sessions

Tags: php, session

I am curious to know how keys and values are encrypted in the session - which standard it uses. Are sessions are decryptable? If not, can we easily extract the values from it?

> PHP Skill: Intermediate.

For example:

Setting Session variables:

```
$_SESSION["greetings"] = "happyNewYear";
$_SESSION["year"] = "2016";
```

Extracting:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I want to know what is happening between setting the variables and saving it.

Comment: what exactly gives you the idea that they are encrypted at all? As far as I know they are stored in a plain (somehow serialized) format in a file on the server, by default, that is.

Comment: They are saved plaintext on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP stores session data in files on the server (it's possible to customize the storage method, but this is the default). Each session has its data stored in a different file, named after the session ID. The session ID is normally a randomly generated string. The contents of the file are the result of `serialize($_SESSION)`.

The session ID is then sent to the client as a cookie, named `PHPSESSID`. When the client sends back this cookie, PHP loads the values from the corresponding file into `$_SESSION`.

The data is not encrypted, the security of this basically depends on the inability to guess the long session ID cookie. See [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking) for more discussion of attacks against this.

Answer (score 0):

By default $_SESSION is saved [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in a plaintext-file on the filesystem of the server.

Comment: Can you provide me the info about how it is encrypted in a cookie that is stored at client side?

Comment: It's not encrypted in the cookie. See my answer for how the cookie relates to the session data.