# Setcookie is not creating cookie

Tags: php, cookies

My login does not seem to be creating a cookie. The form gets all the way to the cookie creation portion of the script and even echos that a cookie was made but it does not actually create one.

Here is the cookie portion of my code:

```
if (!$error) {

    if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
        setcookie('guruemail', $loginemail, time() + 86400 * 365, '/', NULL);
        setcookie('gurupassword',  md5($loginpassword), time() + 86400 * 365, '/', NULL);
echo "Long-term cookie made";
        } else {
        setcookie('guruemail', $loginemail, false, '/', NULL);
        setcookie('gurupassword',  md5($loginpassword), false, '/', NULL);
echo "Short-term cookie made";
    }

}
```

The login can be visited at http://protein.guru/signin.phtml

The cookie test can be viewed at: http://protein.guru/testcookie.php

Here is the cookietest code:

```
<?php
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$guruemail];
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$gurupassword];
?>
```

For the sign-in:

I am using the email: tester3651@outlook.com

Password is: meatloaf

Note:Possible newbie mistake? -- I do not have a session_start(); anywhere in either code. Not sure if I would need that for a straight cookie login.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You should never store login credentials in cookies.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE` or you'll be asking for a bad time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:
Access the $_COOKIE arrays with strings, instead of a variables.

```
<?php
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['guruemail'];
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['gurupassword'];
?>
```

Comment: It took me a few glances to see what was different in your answer. FWIW, it may be useful to mention replacing the variable with a string

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much.. can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need quotes around the cookie variable

```
<?php
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['guruemail'];
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['gurupassword'];
?>
```

Actually it would be much more secure to use `$_SESSION` instead for users login as users can manually set `$_COOKIE`.

More details at the following answer: [Making login more secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131251/making-login-more-secure/35131364#35131364)

Comment: +1 for the info. I'll look into sessions but I check the cookies against a database with salted passwords etc. Should be fine for what I'm doing but I do have some concern for people that have cookies disabled. Thanks