# Login issue with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I have created a website, I have to login to view this site, now I have copied all files into a new directory and created a separate database for that.

The problem is whenever I am logging in one site the other one is also logging in, and also for log out. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? My server is running on localhost (XAMPP).

I followed this tutorial to create login page: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm

Comment: This question is far too vague - please give some examples of the code you are having problems with.

Comment: you're not really thinking of going live with that, are you?

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me why this is happening"* - No idea; I'm not "there".

Comment: *"Thanks"* - For what? we haven't even done anything yet. You haven't told us what's not working?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have linked a url in the question and there is the code i am using in.

Comment: so why are pinging me back then if you accepted an answer? I asked my comments and the one from @Ross prior to mine and only now have you surfaced answering me/us.

Comment: I apologise for that!! Actually something wrong happened to my internet connection so i wrote it before and then accepted the answare then mistakenly submitted the comment. Sorry!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When us store data in the session like you do at `$_SESSION['login_user']`, this session stored data is for your domain. When you copy the application in an other directory, it still runs under the same domain thus it will access the same session data. You can fix this by making the session data key unique to its directory ex. `$_SESSION[$domain.'_login_user']` with $domain being some application specific variable.

Also take a look into session hijacking when using sessions, you are definitely not using them safely: [PHP Session Fixation / Hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking)

Comment: Thanks, I understood why this is happening. Problem Fixed.!!