# Handling session in real life

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-storage

I made a dummy website where I store some `data` in the `session Storage` and change `features` of the interface based on that. I know this is not `secure` at all, so I am curious how that is done in real life ?

Here is a snippet of my code so you can get an `idea` of what´s about. I am using `PHP` on the `server side`. Would it be the way to go with PHP `$_SESSION` in this scenario ?

```
function sessionUser() {


      // for ADMIN view 
      if ( sessionStorage.getItem( 'role' ) == "admin" ) {


          showWelcomeMessage();
          showAdminInterface();
          getProductData();
          getUserData();
          getSubscriberData();
      }

      // for USER view 
      if (sessionStorage.getItem( 'role' ) == "user" ) {

          showWelcomeMessage();
          showUserInterface();
          getProductData();
      }

  }
```

Comment: Uhm..... nnnno. You cannot access the browser html5 storage like that in php.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I think they are saying would they use `$_SESSION` instead of session storage

Comment: @Pete ... ah. Yeah, that would make more sense lol ;)

Comment: Do I need to access that, in order to do what I want to do ? I just need an alternative.

Comment: I would go with the php session but make sure it's secured: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking

Comment: The article @Pete linked is a good one to clamp down the php sessions. Its a real solid start. If your site will be SSL'd (https), then forcing the session cookie to `secure` and `httponly` is something you should do too.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use PHP in this scenario - you could use analogically `$_SESSION['role']` to `sessionStorage.getItem('role')` but in PHP script on server side. Depending on the session value in PHP you can process the template you want to show to the user or by plain PHP or by using one the existing template engines like Twig or Blade. Or if you would like to send just API data to the user instead of the whole templates you can do that as well by conditioning the data by values stored in $_SESSION variable. There is no really **too much** difference - the most important difference is that noone can easily see values of session stored on the server side (unless someone did not stole your cookies, which are used to identify sessions with browsers, and pretended to be you), so on server side session you can store more **confidential data** including **tokens**. Other differences are in **lifetime** and **expiration** triggers.